# Configure an initial state of the redux store in react-native-debugger?

Tags: react-native, redux, react-native-debugger

Is it possible **to configure an initial state of the redux store** in react-native-debugger?

I'm imagining pointing it towards a JSON file on my disk or something like that.

This would allow be to have **arbitrary places in user journeys as my starting point**, that require a complex state of the redux store to already be present.

Comment: do you actually want some redux store to be present when you start/restart your app ? if so then you can hydrate the store when the app launches

Comment: Yes, that's what I want! What does "hydrating the store" mean?

Comment: its just fancy way of saying restoring the old saved store, I have posted the exmaple on how you can retrieve the store and save it

Answer (score -1):

Before creating the store just read the json file that you need with your inital state and call it that way:

```
// store.js
import { data } from "yourFile.json";
...

const mydata = JSON.parse(data);
const store = createStore(
  app,
  mydata
);
```